# Tasks in SharePoint Online don't show up in Outlook for all users

Tags: sharepoint-online, tasks, outlook

We have Tasks set up in SharePoint Online but they aren't showing up in everyone's Outlook (desktop or online). It works fine for some people but not all.

Here are things I've confirmed:

- Everyone has Edit permissions for the tasks through the Member group of the site.
- Everyone can see and edit the task list through a browser.
- In Outlook -> Info:

  - Everyone is logged into Microsoft Exchange through their company email.
  - Under *Account and Social Network Settings* everyone is set to access `https://outlook.office365.com/owa/example.com` (where *example.com* is our company URL).
- In Outlook -> Office Account everyone's connected services includes OneDrive and Sites at their company email address.

For the people where it does work, clicking Tasks in Outlook shows task lists from all the SharePoint Tasks apps from all the sub-sites of our main site under "My Tasks". For the people where it doesn't work, the only things they see under "My Tasks" are their local "To-Do List" and "Tasks" items.

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be related to the fact that Microsoft is removing the "Tasks" feature from SharePoint Online. According to the KB below, tasks in SharePoint Online will continue to sync only until September, 2015.

Check the "More Information" on the link below:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2998445

If that is what is really happening, perhaps newly created accounts (created after Sept. 2014) could present problems in such functionality.

Can you confirm if the users that are seeing this problem are recent?

Comment: That looks like it only applies to personal task lists (e.g. https://contoso-my.sharepoint.com/personal/sarad_contoso_onmicrosoft_com/AllTasks.aspx), not task lists set up with the Tasks app in a sub-site.